# cannot insert values into table(mysql)

Tags: mysql

i have created a table in MYSQL,

```
query:{create table first_prize(a varchar(9));}
```

but when i try to insert a value to the table,

```
query:{INSERT INTO first_prize VALUES(WU-345895);}
```

it shows an error like this:

> Error
>
> SQL query:
>
> INSERT INTO first_prize VALUES(WU-34589)
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'WU' in 'field list'

why it is shown like that??
and how i can insert that value to the column??

Comment: Change `VALUES(WU-345895)` to `VALUES('WU-345895')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a string

`INSERT INTO first_prize VALUES('WU-34589')`

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the value with single quotations marks as the data type is varchar and is expecting a string value 
    INSERT INTO first_prize VALUES('WU-34589')

Comment: i want to add -

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write the `INSERT INTO` statement in two ways.

The first way specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', ...);
```

If you are adding values for all the columns of the table, you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query. However, make sure the order of the values is in the same order as the columns in the table. The `INSERT INTO` syntax would be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', ...);
```